# Fix a variable in SelectInput (RShiny)

Tags: r, select, shiny

I have a selectInput and want to fix one input variable, i.e. you can choose different variables, but one variable is always selected.
How can I program this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share minimum working code.

Comment: output$DynamicInput<-renderUI({ selectInput("Input1","Selected Input Variables for Period 1",choices = c( "x","y","z"),
                                            selected = c("x",  "y") ,selectize = T,multiple = T,width = "100%")
The variable "x" should always be selected.

Comment: So you are saying user should not be able to unselect "x", right?

Comment: Yes, right! @Shree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job, letter `a` will always be selected

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("letters", "Choose a letter:",choices = letters,selected = letters[1],multiple = T)
  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {

    observeEvent(input$letters, {
      updateSelectInput(session, "letters", selected = c(letters[1], 
      input$letters))
    }, ignoreNULL = F)        
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What does "session" mean?

Comment: A shiny session object is a specific data structure in shiny that records one instance of the relationship between one user and shiny. You can find more info on that [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/session.html).

Comment: Just using `observeEvent(input$letters, {
        updateSelectInput(session, "letters", selected = c(letters[1], input$letters))
    }, ignoreNULL = F)` works as well!